# Apply UDF to SparseVector column in spark 2.0

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to apply a UDF to a column in a PySpark df containing SparseVectors (created using pyspark.ml.feature.IDF). Originally, I was trying to apply a more involved function, but am getting the same error with any application of a function. So for the sake of an example:

```
udfSum = udf(lambda x: np.sum(x.values), FloatType()) 
df = df.withColumn("vec_sum", udfSum(df.idf)) 
df.take(10)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling 
z:org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvaluatePython.takeAndServe. 
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: 
Task 0 in stage 55.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 
in stage 55.0 (TID 111, 10.0.11.102): net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException:
expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)
```

If I convert the df to Pandas and apply the function, I can confirm that FloatType() is the correct response type. This may be related, but the error is different: [Issue with UDF on a column of Vectors in PySpark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905740/issue-with-udf-on-a-column-of-vectors-in-pyspark-dataframe).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Convert output to `float`:

```
udf(lambda x: float(np.sum(x.values)), FloatType())
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!